# Quantifying the similarity of distributions

Tags: distributions, distance-functions

I'm looking to quantify the similarity / difference of two income distribution pairs and then compare the quantity with other distribution pairs.

Any pair of distributions have the same number of observations and same supports.

The number of observations across the pairs and the supports change from pair to pair.

How could I quantify the difference of the pair of distributions in such a way that I could use the resulting quantity to compare the difference of a pair to the difference in some other pair?

For Context:

I'm interested in the composition effects of aging on the income distribution. i.e. What the income distribution would look like if the age conditional income distributions remained constant, but the age distribution of the population changed.

I'm using the CEPR-ORG US micro dataset. The first distribution in the pair is the actual empirical distribution of the data (say for year 2013). For the second distribution I reweight the year 2013 data to replicate some counterfactual distribution (say 1950), and take the empirical distribution of the reweighted data.

I'm looking for quantifying how "influencial, important, relevant..." the age composition effects are. In the future I'll expand the work to other countries. I would like to present the results in a simple way: "in US the importancce of age composition is 2, but in Spain it is 4."

Comment: A common method to compare similarity between distributions is the Kullback-Leibler (KL)-divergence.

Comment: Do you know if the Kullback-Leibler (KL)-divergence is influenced a lot by the number of discrete values of the distribution? What I have in mind is that if I have one discrete income distribution pair which can take 200 different values and another pair that can take 1000 different values are my Kullback-Leibler (KL)-divergence measures comparable?

Comment: For income distributions maybe Gini measure of inequality? Maybe https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Income-Distribution-Anthony-Atkinson/dp/0444594302  or have a look at relative distribution methods?